# Animate background-position not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to animate background position but is not working. Is this possible to animate this

```
<head>
    <style>
        .test{ background:#F00}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('a').click(function(){
                $(this).animate({backgroundPosition:'-50px 10px'}, 200);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">click</a>
    <div>check....</div>
</body>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [animate backgroundPosition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380904/animate-backgroundposition)

Comment: Are you using any plugin?

Comment: For what it's worth, GSAP can handle this for you either in its standalone form or you can load its jQuery plugin and your code above will work fine (no special fixes necessary because the fancy footwork is done under the hood, including compatibility with older flavors of IE). http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check [jQuery animate page](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) you can read that :

**Animate**

*All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color() plugin is used).*

That being said, background-position use 2 values. A solution is to splice the value.

Here' how* :

```
$(this).animate({
  'background-position-x' : '-50px',
  'background-position-y' : '10px'
}, 200);
```

*I may have inverted your 2 values, i never remember wich one is `x` and wich one is `y`.

**EDIT**

Since firefox doesnt support `background-position-x` and `y`, here a code to fix it :

```
var pos = {x : '', y : ''};
$('a').click(function(){
    var that = $(this);
    that.animate({
        'background-position-x' : '-50px',
        'background-position-y' : '10px'
    },{
      duration : 200, 
      step : function(a,b){
         if(b.prop == "backgroundPositionX"){
             pos.x = a + b.unit
         }else if(b.prop == "backgroundPositionY"){
             pos.y = a + b.unit
         }
      },
      progress : function(){
         that.css('background-position', pos.x + ' ' + pos.y);
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, firefox doesnt support it, but I fixed it, take a look!

Comment: Hi it is not working in firefox at all. But i want to now what is .unit is used for and what value it will give

Comment: .unit is the unit used during the animation. In this case, unit = px, so pos.x will =  'X px'. And for me, it is working perfectly in firefox : http://jsfiddle.net/np6bG/

Answer (score 1):

I forgot where I came across this, but here is a little pug-in that does the trick quite nicely:

```
(function($){$.extend($.fx.step,{backgroundPosition:function(c){if(c.state===0&&typeof c.end=='string'){var d=$.curCSS(c.elem,'backgroundPosition');d=toArray(d);c.start=[d[0],d[2]];var e=toArray(c.end);c.end=[e[0],e[2]];c.unit=[e[1],e[3]]}var f=[];f[0]=((c.end[0]-c.start[0])*c.pos)+c.start[0]+c.unit[0];f[1]=((c.end[1]-c.start[1])*c.pos)+c.start[1]+c.unit[1];c.elem.style.backgroundPosition=f[0]+' '+f[1];function toArray(a){a=a.replace(/left|top/g,'0px');a=a.replace(/right|bottom/g,'100%');a=a.replace(/([0-9\.]+)(\s|\)|$)/g,"$1px$2");var b=a.match(/(-?[0-9\.]+)(px|\%|em|pt)\s(-?[0-9\.]+)(px|\%|em|pt)/);return[parseFloat(b[1],10),b[2],parseFloat(b[3],10),b[4]]}}})})(jQuery);
```

And in use:

```
$(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        $(this).animate({backgroundPosition: "(-50px 10px)"}, 200);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hQY4U/)**

I think that jQuery can't animate the `background-position`. One solution, is using transition, in CSS:

```
a {
    -webkit-transition: background-position 0.6s;
    -moz-transition:    background-position 0.6s;
    -ms-transition:     background-position 0.6s;
    -o-transition:      background-position 0.6s;
    transition:         background-position 0.6s;
}
```

And just change the `background-position` in jQuery with `.css()` method:

```
$(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        $(this).css('background-position', '250px 250px');
    });
});
```